# Hibernate Search: Perform search query without database transaction

Tags: hibernate-search

I use Hibernate Search 5.11.5 in my Spring Boot project. For searching I use projection so theoretically I do not need an open transaction. But if I delete the `@Transactional` annotation and I call `Search.getFullTextEntityManager(em)`, I get the exception

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No transactional EntityManager available
     at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:288)
     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy142.unwrap(Unknown Source)
     at org.hibernate.search.jpa.Search.getSession(Search.java:55)
     at org.hibernate.search.jpa.Search.getFullTextEntityManager(Search.java:49)
```

Because I consequently use projection - is there any way to prevent this forced usage of a transaction?

Comment: Not sure of your question, but every database query runs inside a transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The problem

It's a bit complicated, but I'll try to explain the best I can...

Yes, Hibernate Search is able to run search queries without a transaction. Even if you're loading entities, though obviously that's not recommended. In any case, that's definitely possible if you're just using projections and not loading any entity.

However, Hibernate Search always needs a Session, even if it's not loading any entity. Let's call that a limitation of the internal architecture. So you don't need a transaction, but you do need a session.

Now, the entity managers injected by Spring are a bit special in that they are proxies. The `EntityManager` proxy injected into your beans will automatically create a real `EntityManager` and delegate to it... but only if you're in a transaction. If you're not in a transaction, you'll get the error you're seeing.

So it's not that Hibernate Search *directly* needs a transaction, but rather that it needs an actual `EntityManager` (not just a proxy), and (at least by default) Spring will only allow that within a transaction.

### Solutions... ?

I'd suggest you reconsider and use a transaction, unless you have very specific reasons to not want to, such as a limited database connection pool.

Otherwise...

There are probably solutions built inside Spring. `OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter` comes to mind, though that's a controversial solution. Maybe there are others, but I'm a bit rusty when it comes to Spring, unfortunately.

Alternatively, you can try opening a `Session` yourself. As long as you don't load anything and you don't open a transaction, it should be rather cheap performance-wise (it won't acquire a database connection, in particular). I assume that's what you're after?

It would go like this:

```
@PersistenceUnit
EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

public List<MyProjection> search(...) {
    try (Session session = entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class)
            .openSession()) {
        // ... do your things ...
        return hits;
    }
}
```

Ultimately, at some point in the future, there will be a dedicated API for session-less (and thus transaction-less) search queries: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-3519
But for now, the solution above will have to do.

Comment: Thank you. I think the main problem are index queries in a parallel loop. Since this seems to prevent reusing the transaction that looks like my main problem. I should rethink that.